# "takeWhile (<= (maxBound :: Word8)) primes" hangs

Tags: haskell

Today I was up to find out how many prime numbers there are that fit the bounds of `Word8`, but this most trivial task gave me an unexpected... *absence of result*.

```
λ import Data.Numbers.Primes
λ import Data.Word
λ takeWhile (<= (maxBound :: Word8)) primes
[2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,25,29,31,35,37,41,43,47,49,53,55,59,61,71,73,
77,79,83,85,89,95,97,101,103,107,109,115,119,121,125,127,133,137,139,
145,149,151,157,161,163,167,173,175,179,185,187,191,197,199,203,205,
209,215,217,223,235^CInterrupted.
```

As you may see, not only does this evaluation not terminate, but the numbers yielded are not all prime!

I proceeded to dance around the case:

```
λ maxBound :: Word8
255

λ takeWhile (<= 255) primes
[2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,
97,101,103,107,109,113,127,131,137,139,149,151,157,163,167,173,179,181
,191,193,197,199,211,223,227,229,233,239,241,251]

λ takeWhile (<= (maxBound :: Word8)) [1..]
[1,2,3, {- ..., -} 253,254,255]
-- This of course works, so I do not present the consecutive
-- natural numbers inbetween 3 and 253.

λ takeWhile (<= 255) $ take 255 primes
[2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,
97,101,103,107,109,113,127,131,137,139,149,151,157,163,167,173,179,181
,191,193,197,199,211,223,227,229,233,239,241,251]

λ takeWhile (<= (maxBound  :: Word8)) $ take 255 primes
[2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,25,29,31,35,37,41,43,47,49,53,55,59,61,71,73,
77,79,83,85,89,95,97,101,103,107,109,115,119,121,125,127,133,137,139,
145,149,151,157,161,163,167,173,175,179,185,187,191,197,199,203,205,
209,215,217,223,235^CInterrupted.
```

So, `takeWhile` only works when we avoid either `maxBound` or `primes`.

How am I to interpret these findings?

---

I use the latest stable `stack` snapshot and [this primes library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/primes).

Comment: That is because you ask `primes` to generate a list of `Word8` primes. And some operations are proken over the **Z_256** field.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Wouldn't that mean the library is broken for all bounded types? (Broken as in "a pure function entering infinite loop in a finite case".)

Comment: BTW, `(<= maxBound)` is always true

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem is quite interesting, but it's not in `takeWhile`; it's in `primes`:

Since `primes` is able to return whatever type you want, its implementation probably silently uses that type internally. So, when you ask it to return `Word8` primes, it fails *internally*:

```
λ take 20 (primes :: [Word8])
[2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,25,29,31,35,37,41,43,47,49,53,55]
```

I suppose a workaround is to use a fixed type for the primes generator (e.g. `(primes :: [Int])`, and just `fromIntegral` your limit value. And possibly file a bug to the library as well.

Comment: [I've actually filed the bug myself](https://github.com/sebfisch/primes/issues/5), BTW.

Answer (score 5):

The actual issue was found by Bartek Banachewicz above.

However, note that the predicate `(<= (maxBound :: Word8))` is *always true*.
It is equivalent to `p` where:

```
p :: Word8 -> Bool
p x = x <= maxBound
```

Now, the important thing is that the `x` argument here (which is implicit in the original code) is a `Word8`. So, we are comparing an arbitrary `Word8` to the maximum number representable in `Word8`. This is always true!

If you need a numeric type conversion, you have to be explicit. E.g.

```
takeWhile (<= fromIntegral (maxBound :: Word8)) (primes :: [Int])
```

Now, the implicit `x` is an `Int`, and `fromIntegral` correctly turns `256::Word8` into `256::Int`.